# People Picker Field is not working in Word Template when Modern Authentication is Enabled for SharePoint 2013 Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, person-or-group

People Picker Field is not working in Word Template when Modern Authentication is Enabled for SharePoint 2013 Server. It starts working when we updated EnbleADAL to 0, but this we have to do on every user's system separately. Can anyone please tell me how we can resolve this?

The strange thing is it is working in out INT and Training environment.